# Json Deserialization via Winforms using riot API won't display data from Datagrid

Tags: api, winforms

I'm working on a WinForms application which utilizes the RiotAPI to output data into a Datagrid. I managed to deserialize the object, however the information will not output. I set my Datagrid to be a datasource of the object. Here's my code.

```
private void GetAPIData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/USERNAMEHERE?api_key=INSERTKEYHERE");
        SummonerV4 summoner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummonerV4>(json);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = summoner;
        // MessageBox.Show(json);
    }
```

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrmeE.png)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that … `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummonerV4>(json);` … is returning any data? Are you adding the columns to grid from the designer…? Or … are the columns created automatically from the `DataSource`? The grid’s default setting for the `AutoGenerateColumns` property is `true`… so it is difficult to tell where the columns came from. If the columns came from the `summoner` data source, then this would indicate that there is no data.

Comment: It does return data as if I do the Messagebox.Show(json); it displays all the info within a window. The datasource is SummonerV4 and the Automatic Size and Rows are set to AllCells.

Comment: `MessageBox(json)` may show the data… however what does `summoner` contain? In other words look at `summoner` AFTER… `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummonerV4>(json);` … has executed. Look and see if `summoner` actually has data. Also, I am not sure where “Automatic Size and Rows” pertains to my previous question.